# Django inlineformset_factory

Tags: django, python-2.7, many-to-many, inline-formset, formset

I'm stuck on a problem with Django framework. In detail, user can create a Group and associate Member (>=1 && <=3) to the group. Each member is identified by email address (unique). However, the same member can partecipate with different name and surname in different groups. So I have a many to many relationship (using through) between Group and Member.
In my view I've an inlineformset. However when I submit the form I always get:

> archi_groupmember.group_id may not be NULL

I've changed the widget for the MemberGroup form, because the user don't have to select a member from a select but he has to type the member's mail. 
So I think I should persist the member just before to save the MemberGroup, but I don't know how to do it!

I'm totally new to Django, I'm following the docs.

Thank you all for any help!!

Here a page screenshot just to clarify: http://postimg.org/image/bndh5ug29/

Following my code.

Models.py:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    limit = Q(active = True)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, limit_choices_to = limit)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    code = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Member(models.Model):
    groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, through='GroupMember')
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email


class GroupMember(models.Model):
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
@user_passes_test(first_login_check, login_url='/detail')
def partecipate(request):
    from django.forms import TextInput

    MemberFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Group, Member.groups.through, form=GroupMemberForm, can_delete=False, extra=3, widgets={'member': TextInput() } )
    if request.method == 'POST':

        form = GroupForm(request.POST)
        member_set = MemberFormSet(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():

        for form in member_set: 
                print vars( form['member'] )

            group = form.save(commit=False)
            group.user = request.user
            group.code = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for x in range(10))
            group.save()

            member_set = MemberFormSet(request.POST, instance=group)
            member_set = member_set.save(commit=False)


            payment = Payment()
            payment.group = group
            payment.invoice = _createInvoice(group.project.id, group.id)
            payment.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
        else:
            return render(request, "partecipate.html", { 'form': form, 'member_set' : member_set })
    else:
        form = GroupForm()
        form.Meta.model.project.queryset = Project.objects.filter(active=True)
        member_set = MemberFormSet(initial=[ {'name': request.user.first_name,'surname': request.user.last_name,'member':request.user.email} ])

    return render(request, "partecipate.html", { 'form': form, 'member_set' : member_set })
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of Django are you using?

Since 1.3 the help docs has an example of using ***inlineformset_factory***.  And the example (link below) clearly shows passing in an instance of the *parent* record.  Without that, your formsets will not be linked to real data.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#using-an-inline-formset-in-a-view

I'm also suspicious of specifying the *Member.groups.through* table class as the child.  I would think you should leave it as *Member*, because the through table is part of the internal machinery.